# WebDriverAgent not compiling in macOS

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am trying to run appium automation on iPhone real device. For that I am trying to execute WebDriverAgent (Ref.: https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/installing-webdriveragent-for-ios-devices.html)
I executed these commands in terminal:
cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent
mkdir -p Resources/WebDriverAgent.bundle
sh ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh -d

On executing the last command, I get the error:
Building universal frameworks with common architectures is not possible. The device and simulator slices for "RoutingHTTPServer" both build for: arm64
Rebuild with --use-xcframeworks to create an xcframework bundle instead.

macOS Version: 10.15.7 (Catalina)
Appium Version: 1.15.1